# Дефис или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"В школах, учебных комплексах (кроме средних школ - училищ олимпийского резерва),..."
В нормативном акте сочетание "средние школы - училища олимпийского резерва" прописано через дефис с пробелами. Но, как мне кажется, здесь нужно тире с пробелами. Так как же правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дефис с пробелами - это уже тире. Вот мне, например, лень печатать *"—"* *(alt+0151)*, поэтому ставлю *"-"*. То есть на всяких форумах и т.п. это оправдано, но в нормативных актах правила должны быть соблюдены. Дефис соединяет части слова, а тире - части предложения. В случае этого акта *"школа-училище"* - это нечто целое, поэтому должно писаться через дефис, следовательно, без пробелов.